# How to get remove duplicate salary employess and remove latest employee based on empid using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [
  {
    empid: 1,
    cmd: {
      salary: 200
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 2,
    cmd: {
      salary: 600
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 3,
    cmd: {
      salary: 700
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 4,
    cmd: {
      salary: 300
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 5,
    cmd: {
      salary: 400
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 6,
    cmd: {
      salary: 300
    }
  }
];
```

As empid 4 and 6 has got salary of 300, I want to remove emp with high id 6.
Final Array should be like,

```
[
  {
    empid: 1,
    cmd: {
      salary: 200
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 2,
    cmd: {
      salary: 600
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 3,
    cmd: {
      salary: 700
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 4,
    cmd: {
      salary: 300
    }
  },
  {
    empid: 5,
    cmd: {
      salary: 400
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following solution that uses an object to maintain a mapping of salaries to employee IDs and then converts back to an array. I like this method because you don't have to do a potentially-expensive array `find` method each loop. Additionally, this method does not depend on the ordering of `empid` keys; this will always yield the lowest `empid`.

Edit: Slightly adjusted implementation to use a filter at the end so we don't have to worry about mapping the original object back in.

```js
var arr = [{empid:1,cmd:{salary:200}},{empid:2,cmd:{salary:600}},{empid:3,cmd:{salary:700}},{empid:4,cmd:{salary:300}},{empid:5,cmd:{salary:400}},{empid:6,cmd:{salary:300}}];

const ids = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.cmd.salary] || el.empid < acc[el.cmd.salary]) {
    acc[el.cmd.salary] = el.empid
  }
  return acc
}, {}));

const newArr = arr.filter(el => ids.includes(el.empid))
  .sort((a, b) => a.empid - b.empid);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: If employee and its cmd contains other fields, should I map all the fields again?

Comment: I made a change to just filter the original array at the end so you don't have to worry about handling extra properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr = [ { empid: 1, cmd: { salary: 200 } }, { empid: 2, cmd: { salary: 600 } }, { empid: 3, cmd: { salary: 700 } }, { empid: 4, cmd: { salary: 300 } }, { empid: 5, cmd: { salary: 400 } }, { empid: 6, cmd: { salary: 300 } }
];

var arr2 = [ { empid: 1, cmd: { salary: 200 } }, { empid: 2, cmd: { salary: 600 } }, { empid: 3, cmd: { salary: 700 } }, { empid: 6, cmd: { salary: 300 } }, { empid: 5, cmd: { salary: 400 } }, { empid: 4, cmd: { salary: 300 } }
];

let result = arr.reduce((state, current) => {
   let prevIndex = state.findIndex(x => x.cmd.salary === current.cmd.salary);
   if(prevIndex === -1){
      state.push(current);
   } else if (state[prevIndex].empid > current.empid) {
       state[prevIndex] = current;
   }
   return state;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. But this will not work, if Array is not sorted by employee Id. Can u pls accomdate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest version

```
arr.filter(
    (employee,i) => !arr.some(
       (elem,j) => employee.cmd.salary === elem.cmd.salary && j < i
    )
);
```

The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

So, when saying `!arr.some` it means I want the array to not have any elements that fit the given condition. It's like saying `none`